# Is second order logic with Henkin semantics finitely axiomatizable in first order logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Second order logic with Henkin semantics is axiomatizable in first order logic, for example, using truth predicates and comprehension axioms for all arities. Is it possible to provide a finite axiomatization as well?

Comment: Do you mean finitely axiomatizable or recursively axiomatizable?

Comment: Finitely, similar to how NBG set theory can.

Comment: I don't know, but this might touch on the differences and relationships between "finitely axiomatizable"and "recursively axiomatizable" (because the comprehension schemas for general semantics / Henkin semantics https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#AxioSecoOrdeLogi seem to basically be the same as those in Peano arithmetic or ZFC) this answer to a related question might help? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4613983/606791 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955523/finite-list-of-axioms-of-mathsfaca-0-reference That it's possible for ACA0 suggests the answer could be yes